# How to set a foreign key to nullable in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a user_id set in log table and now have a problem that I sometimes need to store logs to actions performed by non-logged users.

When I run this migration

```
    Schema::table('users_log', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable()->change();
    });
```

I get an error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1832 Cannot change column 'user_id': used in a foreign key constraint
>   'users_log_user_id_foreign' (SQL: ALTER TABLE users_log CHANGE user_id
>   user_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL)

Comment: you have a foreign key constraint that does not allow null value in user_id. Remove the constraint and you should be fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to drop FK constraint first:

```
$table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
```

Then modify the column and add a new FK constraint.

Also, make sure you're doing this in a separate `Schema::table()` closures.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: @naneri what exactly didn't work? Did you get an error or something? Have you tried to drop FK in one `Schema::table()` closure, modify the column in another and add another FK in another one?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: it did work after I set them in different closures. Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you please note in the answer that foreign key constraint drops should be in different closures.

Comment: @naneri sure. Added. )

Comment: This works! Thank you for the updated answer that needs to run in separate closures.